# expected string-literal before ‘)’ when using static_assert in c++17

Tags: c++11, cmake, c++17

So when I try to build my c++ application I get compile-time error in the following piece of code

```
static_assert(sizeof(int32_t) == 4)
```

This is the error that I get `expected string-literal before ‘)’`

On some investigation I found out that static_assert required a message param in c++11 which was eliminated in c++17. So does it look like my application is being compiled for c++11?

In my CMakeLists.txt file I have the following lines

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)              
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

Shouldn't the above lines build my application for c++17?

Thanks!

**Update1 -- Full Error trace**

```
In file included from <project_root>/src/include/buffer/buffer_pool_manager.h:22:0,
                 from <project_root>/src/include/catalog/simple_catalog.h:8,
                 from <project_root>/src/include/catalog/table_generator.h:6,
                 from <project_root>/src/catalog/table_generator.cpp:1:
<project_root>/src/include/storage/page/page.h:70:39: error: expected ‘,’ before ‘)’ token
   static_assert(sizeof(page_id_t) == 4);
                                       ^
<project_root>/src/include/storage/page/page.h:70:39: error: expected string-literal before ‘)’ token
In file included from <project_root>/src/include/buffer/buffer_pool_manager.h:22:0,
                 from <project_root>/src/buffer/buffer_pool_manager.cpp:13:
<project_root>/src/include/storage/page/page.h:70:39: error: expected ‘,’ before ‘)’ token
   static_assert(sizeof(page_id_t) == 4);
                                       ^
<project_root>/src/include/storage/page/page.h:70:39: error: expected string-literal before ‘)’ token
src/CMakeFiles/bustub_shared.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/bustub_shared.dir/buffer/buffer_pool_manager.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/bustub_shared.dir/buffer/buffer_pool_manager.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
src/CMakeFiles/bustub_shared.dir/build.make:114: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/bustub_shared.dir/catalog/table_generator.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/bustub_shared.dir/catalog/table_generator.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:383: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/bustub_shared.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/bustub_shared.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you checked the actual compilation line being used to make sure the right standard is being passed?

Comment: @StephenNewell I am trying to build the opensource code here https://github.com/cmu-db/bustub. New to c++ and cmake. Where do I check the compilation line?

Comment: Is this the entire error message you get, or is there more to it?

Comment: @IInspectable updated question with full error trace. Although nothing more in it other than compilation failing for a whole bunch of dependent files

Comment: Did you include cstdint?

Comment: @n.m. I see it included in a bunch of places but not in the file that is giving the error.

Comment: @AbdulRahman Try invoking the build with `make VERBOSE=1`. The Makefiles generated by the CMake will start spewing the actual command lines. You could then make two things: 1. Check the last `-std=` argument to the compiler; 2. Check which compiler is picked up and double check the version of that compiler. E.g. is the compiler used is `/home/me/local/bin/gcc`, I would call `/home/me/local/bin/gcc -- version`. Setting the expected standard in the CMake may be not enough. Some distros are shipped with version not supporting some newer dialects.

Answer (score 1):

I changed it to gcc-7 and g++-7 solved my problem.